# How to use the Bradhley Hand font?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I've checked the [Mathfonts](http://www.faq.ktug.org/wiki/uploads/MathFonts.pdf%E2%80%8E) that can be used through `beamer` class. I've successfully used most of the fonts, but when I tried to include the Bradhley Hand font, it did not work (it shows ordinary characters)?! How can I use it?

For example, when I use the following :

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer} 
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ibh} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\frac{ \sqrt{ \mu(i)^{ \frac{3}{2}} (i^{2} -1) } }
{ \sqrt[3]{\rho(i) - 2} + \sqrt[3]{\rho(i) - 1} } $
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

it gives:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX. Can you include a small example that shows the problem as we usually denote it as MWE? Check the [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) for more info about the site in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attempting to use ITC Bradley Hand, presumably you want something like this:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ibh}
\begin{document}
Test

\[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\]

\end{document}
```

Basing your efforts on a suggestion like the last slide in: http://math.ecnu.edu.cn/~latex/slides/beamer/MathFonts.pdf

The footnote there notes `Bradhley (sic) Hand ITC (in TTF) comes with MS Windows` --- if you have the font, then you simply have to install it using a utility like fontinst, or ttf2tfm to install the font using the name ibh and create a font mapping entry --- put the files in the right place, refresh the filename database and font mapping (if necessary) and you're good to go.

Alternately, you could switch to using `xelatex` or `lualatex`, in which case if you have the font installed, something like this will work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}%remove deprecated option
\usefonttheme{serif}%replacement for deprecated [serif] documentclass option
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\setmainfont{Bradley Hand ITC TT Bold}%used Bold, since that's what was bundled w/ Mac OS X
\begin{document}
Test

\[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\]

\end{document}
```

[image: A simple math equation and text]

Comment: That tutorial is getting old. `serif` option is not supported any more but you can switch that on via `\usefonttheme{serif}` instead.