# Type of text in beamer - mathpazo

Tags: beamer, fonts, mathpazo

How can I change the type of text in beamer as shown in the image.
[image: Model]

Comment: The first big step towards a solution is often a minimal working example that shows what you have tried. In its current form, your question may prevent some of those who know the answer from answering just because they are not too keen to punch in stuff from a screen shot.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122267/121799.

Comment: The image you show explains how to do it. Start your document as is shown into the box.